# How can I have the inbox area show once the document is finished loading?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Basically trying to create kind of an inbox for my person portfolio (more of a learning experience, then anything serious, or of use).

Right now when this document loads within an ajax/javascript function, it loads showing ALL emails (instead of just showing the Inbox section by default)

I've tried adding a function in javascript for "on document load" but I believe I may not have the css correct or anything.

My code is below:

```
<div id="messages" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="breadcrumb" class="col-xs-12">
            <a href="#" class="show-sidebar">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
            <ol class="breadcrumb pull-left">
                <li><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Modules</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ol>
            <div id="social" class="pull-right">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="test">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <ul id="messages-menu" class="nav msg-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="" id="msg-inbox">
                            <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Inbox (<?php echo $inboxCount; ?>)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="" id="msg-starred">
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Unread (<?php echo $unreadCount; ?>)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="" id="msg-important">
                            <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Read  (<?php echo $readCount; ?>)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="" id="msg-trash">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Trash (<?php echo $trashCount; ?>)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div id="messages-list" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2">
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getEmails)) {
                        $email_id = $row['email_id'];
                        $emailStatus = $row['emailStatus'];
                        $contactName = $row['contactName'];
                        $contactEmailAddress = $row['contactEmailAddress'];
                        $messageBody = $row['messageBody'];
                        $tempEmailDate = $row['emailDate'];
                        $emailDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($tempEmailDate));
                        $contactName = strtoupper($contactName);
                        $contactEmailAddress = strtoupper($contactEmailAddress);
                        if ($row == 1 && ($emailStatus == 1 || $emailStatus == 2)) {
                            echo "
                                    <div class='row one-list-message msg-inbox-item' id='msg-one'>
                                        <div class='col-xs-1 checkbox'>
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type='checkbox'>$contactName
                                                    <i class='fa fa-square-o small'></i>
                                                </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-xs-9 message-title'>$messageBody</div>
                                        <div class='col-xs-2 message-date'>$emailDate</div>
                                    </div>
                                    ";
                        } else if ($emailStatus == 1 || $emailStatus == 2) {
                            echo "
                                    <div class='row one-list-message msg-inbox-item'>
                                        <div class='col-xs-1 checkbox'>
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type='checkbox'>$contactName
                                                    <i class='fa fa-square-o small'></i>
                                                </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-xs-9 message-title'>$messageBody</div>
                                        <div class='col-xs-2 message-date'>$emailDate</div>
                                    </div>
                                    ";
                        }
                        if ($emailStatus == 1) {
                            // Unread section
                            echo "
                                <div class='row one-list-message msg-starred-item'>
                                    <div class='col-xs-1 checkbox'>
                                        <label>
                                            <input type='checkbox'>$contactName
                                            <i class='fa fa-square-o small'></i>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-xs-9 message-title'>$messageBody</div>
                                    <div class='col-xs-2 message-date'>$emailDate</div>
                                </div>
                                ";
                            $updateEmailStatus = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE emails SET emailStatus='2' WHERE email_id='$email_id'");
                        } else {
                            if ($emailStatus == 2) {
                                // Read section
                                echo "
                                    <div class='row one-list-message msg-important-item'>
                                        <div class='col-xs-1 checkbox'>
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type='checkbox'>$contactName
                                                    <i class='fa fa-square-o small'></i>
                                                </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-xs-9 message-title'>$messageBody</div>
                                        <div class='col-xs-2 message-date'>$emailDate</div>
                                    </div>
                                    ";
                            } else {
                                if ($emailStatus == 3) {
                                    // Deleted section
                                    echo "
                                    <div class='row one-list-message msg-trash-item'>
                                        <div class='col-xs-1 checkbox'>
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type='checkbox'>$contactName
                                                    <i class='fa fa-square-o small'></i>
                                                </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-xs-9 message-title'>$messageBody</div>
                                        <div class='col-xs-2 message-date'>$emailDate</div>
                                    </div>
                                    ";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#msg-inbox').show();
    });
    // Add listener for redraw menu when windows resized
    window.onresize = MessagesMenuWidth;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Add class for correctly view of messages page
        $('#content').addClass('full-content');
        // Run script for change menu width
        MessagesMenuWidth();
        $('#content').on('click','[id^=msg-]', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('[id^=msg-]').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.one-list-message').slideUp('fast');
            $('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'-item').slideDown('fast');
        });
        $('html').animate({scrollTop: 0},'slow');
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone see how I'd do the javascript to have the msg-inbox load when the page loads? instead of loading none and displaying all emails.

Thank you!

Comment: Make demo, use SO code snippets/Plunker/JsFiddle

Comment: What is your definition of "inbox"? Read & Unread, Unread only?

Comment: @Kuya My definition is Read & Unread, so using the id="msg-inbox" i think. I'll try and make a demo

Comment: I can't see any element with msg-inbox id, where it was sopposed to be and what is the content?

Comment: Please show us your complete sql query code. In it there should be something like this... `$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;`

Comment: Then this line would be something like `if ($row_cnt == 1 && ($emailStatus == 1 || $emailStatus == 2)) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to hide and/or show divs, jquery is your best friend. It's simple and looks nice.

Start by wrapping your read & unread messages in a div id of "inbox"

Then give each of your inbox divs an id like "read" & "unread"

Using the code below you can hide/show your individual divs.

Place this between your `<head> </head>` tags

```
<script src="JS/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Unread").click(function(){
    $("#unread").slideToggle(500, function() {
    });
  });
  $("#Read").click(function(){
    $("#read").slideToggle(500, function() {
    });
  });
  $("#Deleted").click(function(){
    $("#deleted").slideToggle(500, function() {
    });
  });
});
</script>
<style>
#unread {
    display: none;
}
#read {
    display: none;
}
#deleted {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Then in the body of your page, you can do something like this

```
<div id="inbox">
<div id="unread_msgs">
<button id="Unread">Show/Hide Unread</button>
<div id="unread"> 
  <p>These </p>
  <p>are</p>
  <p>my</p>
  <p>unread</p>
  <p>messages</p>
</div><!-- end unread -->
</div><!-- end unread_msgs -->
<div id="read_msgs">
<button id="Read">Show/Hide Read</button>
<div id="read"> 
  <p>These </p>
  <p>are</p>
  <p>my</p>
  <p>read</p>
  <p>messages</p>
</div><!-- end read -->
</div><!-- end read_msgs -->
</div><!-- end inbox -->
<div id="deleted_msgs">
<button id="Deleted">Show/Hide Deleted</button>
<div id="deleted"> 
  <p>These </p>
  <p>are</p>
  <p>my</p>
  <p>deleted</p>
  <p>messages</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. It should get you going in the right direction.

**References**

[jquery slidetoggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: I think I've fixed my issue using a similar approach! Thank you!